# Функция не видит переменной . JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

В теле документа у меня прописано

```html
<div id="okno_print"></div>
<script>
  dir = "subscribe/mdadmin/p_ajax/";

  function get_users() {
    document.getElementById("okno_print").innerHTML = "<a href='#' onclick='confirmJS(\"delet\"," + activate_delete_users + ");return false;'>test</a>";
  }

  function confirmJS(num = false, funct = false) {
    alert(dir); //тут нормально
    funct(num);
    return false;
  }

  function activate_delete_users(op_users) {
    alert(dir); //тут пусто
  }

  get_users();
</script>
```

Объясните, почему в функции, которая передается в виде аргумента пустая переменная dir ? Спасибо

Comment: `onclick='confirmJS(\"delet\",activate_delete_users);return false;'`

Comment: это все потому, что неверно строка собирается!

Comment: спасибо. Убрал кавычки

Comment: @Grundy как и полагается женскому роду :D

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian и что значит "//тут пусто"? Вы хотите сказать, что `alert` появляется, но с пустой строкой?

Comment: @Igor, да, именно это и происходит :-)

Answer (score 2):

При собирании строки с html обработчиками событий, нужно быть предельно осторожным.

Для того, чтобы понять, почему работает именно так, нужно разобраться, что вообще происходит в данном примере.

Необходимо определить, какая строка в итоге получается.
Строка

```
"<a href='#' onclick='confirmJS(\"delet\","+activate_delete_users+");return false;'>test</a>"
```

Преобразуется в следующую

```
"<a href="#" onclick="confirmJS('delet',function activate_delete_users(op_users) { alert(dir); });return false;">test</a>"
```

Таким образом в функцию *confirmJS* передается не уже определенная функция, а вновь созданная.

При этом, важной особенностью inline обработчиков является то, что они создаются в контексте html элемента, это означает, что `this` в строке

```
"<a href="#" onclick="console.log(this);return false;">test</a>"
```

будет ссылаться на элемент `a`, по которому кликнули. Кроме этого, все переменные используемые в строке обработчика в первую очередь будут искаться в элементе `a`.

Если посмотреть свойства элемента `a`, можно увидеть в них [свойство `dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dir) наследуемое от *HTMLElement*.

Значение именно этого свойства и выводится в данном случае.

Исправить поведение можно с помощью нескольких способов:

1. Не собирать строку вообще, а создавать элементы вручную. Например так:

   ```
   var deleteButton = document.createElement('a');
   deleteButton.href = '#';
   deleteButton.textContent = 'Test';
   deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
     confirmJS('delet', activate_delete_users);
     return false;
   });
   document.getElementById("okno_print").appendChild(deleteButton);
   ```

   Этот вариант позволит избежать всех проблем связанных с собиранием строки.
2. Не вставлять в строку функцию. Это позволит избежать создание этой функции при каждом клике в контексте элемента. Строка в этом случае будет выглядеть следующим образом (метод из [комментария @Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634691/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-js#comment895405_634691))

   ```
   "<a href='#' onclick='confirmJS(\"delet\", activate_delete_users);return false;'>test</a>"
   ```

   В этом случае, при создании обработчика будет использована ссылка на существующую функцию *activate_delete_users*.
3. Так как в функции используется глобальная переменная, к ней можно получить доступ как к свойству объекта *window*.

   ```
   function activate_delete_users(op_users) {
       alert(window.dir); //тут уже не пусто
   }
   ```
4. Переименовать глобальную переменную, например:

   ```
   directory = "subscribe/mdadmin/p_ajax/";
   ```

Пример:

```js
var dir = "subscribe/mdadmin/p_ajax/";
var directory = "subscribe/mdadmin/p_ajax/";

function get_users() {
  wayFour();
  wayThree();
  wayTwo();
  wayOne();
}

function wayOne() {
  var deleteButton = document.createElement('a');
  deleteButton.href = '#';
  deleteButton.textContent = 'Way 1';
  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    confirmJS('delet', activate_delete_users);
    return false;
  });
  document.getElementById("okno_print").appendChild(deleteButton);
}

function wayTwo() {
  document.getElementById("okno_print").innerHTML += "<a href='#' onclick='confirmJS(\"delet\", activate_delete_users);return false;'>Way 2</a> ";
}

function wayThree() {
  document.getElementById("okno_print").innerHTML += "<a href='#' onclick='confirmJS(\"delet\", " + activate_delete_users_way_3 + ");return false;'>Way 3</a> ";
}

function wayFour() {
  document.getElementById("okno_print").innerHTML += "<a href='#' onclick='confirmJS(\"delet\", " + activate_delete_users_way_4 + ");return false;'>Way 4</a> ";
}

function confirmJS(num = false, funct = false) {
  console.log('confirmJS', dir);
  funct(num);
  return false;
}

function activate_delete_users(op_users) {
  console.log('activate_delete_users', dir);
}

function activate_delete_users_way_3(op_users) {
  console.log("activate_delete_users_way_3", window.dir); //тут уже не пусто
}

function activate_delete_users_way_4(op_users) {
  console.log("activate_delete_users_way_4", directory); //тут уже не пусто
}
get_users();
```

```html
<div id="okno_print"></div>
```